# ORACLE - Remote execute proc with RC IN OUT Parameter

Tags: oracle

This is the parameter for a procedure which i would like to execute from another Proc also on Oracle

What input is used for RC?

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE        PROC (

   RC          IN OUT PKG_OPREPORTING.RPTCURSOR)

   AS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to look at package `PKG_OPREPORTING`, find `RPTCURSOR` in there and then you'll know.

That's not a *built-in* Oracle datatype, as far as I can tell, so - there's no way we could know that.